# Error in getting XML and parsing it

Tags: android, xml

```
public String getMetaData() {
    String errors = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://in2streaming.com:9999/stats?sid=1.xml");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        // Error Here:
        Document doc = db.parse(conn.getInputStream().toString());

        // get the root node
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("SHOUTCASTSERVER");
        Node node=nodeList.item(0);
        // the  node has three child nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
            Node temp=node.getChildNodes().item(i);
            if(temp.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("SONGTITLE")){
                return temp.getTextContent();
            }
        }
        return "Couldn't reach XML";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return "Exception ";
    }
}
```

Calling this function via Runnable, Got Exception android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
I might change the link to http://in2streaming.com:9999/7.html and use HTMl parser instead

```
// Refresh meta data
private final Runnable refresh_meta = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(m_context, getMetaData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        m_handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the error? post the logcat

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at cloud.SmoothRadio.nagare.MainJava.showNotification(MainJava.java:60)
                                                                             at cloud.SmoothRadio.nagare.MainJava.onClick(MainJava.java:120)

Comment: This error does not belong to the source code posted in the question.

Comment: @mazenelzoor You may be getting NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Document doc = db.parse(conn.getInputStream());

Comment: @mazenelzoor   Add code: catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} and post the correct logcat error

Comment: @MM yes it's a NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @mazenelzoor see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For NetworkOnMainThreadException(You can also use AsyncTask):

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getMetaData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If you want to Schedule every 5 sec.

You can use ScheduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        worker.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresh_meta,
                1,  //initial delay
                5, //run every 5 seconds
                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And Update your Runnable as

```
private Runnable refresh_meta = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final String text = getMetaData();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  Toast.makeText(m_context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              }
                          }
            );


        }
    };
```

Also,

Change   `Document doc = db.parse(conn.getInputStream().toString());` to

```
Document doc = db.parse(conn.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I failed to mention that I'm calling this function via Runnable

Comment: @mazenelzoor can you also add that code to question posted

Comment: @mazenelzoor I have used ScheduledExecutorService instead of Handler.Update your Runnable refresh_meta; and use try above code.

Comment: Nevermind I added the code outside OnCreate lol... Thanks so so much man/mam :)

Answer (score 1):

First some remarks:

a) Do not muffle the exceptions like you do here :

```
catch (Exception e) {
    return "Exception ";
}
```

This way you will never know what was the exception that was thrown. It is better to log/print the exception's stack trace, for example:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Error", e);
    return "Exception";
}
```

b) `conn.getInputStream().toString()` doesn't do what you suppose it does (convert the `InputStream` to `String`). `DocumentBuilder`'s [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)) method takes an `InputStream` as parameter no need to convert it to `String`.

Having the above in mind here is your method:

```
public String getMetaData() {
    String errors = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://in2streaming.com:9999/stats?sid=1.xml");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        // Error Here:
        Document doc = db.parse(conn.getInputStream());

        // get the root node
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("SHOUTCASTSERVER");
        Node node=nodeList.item(0);
        // the  node has three child nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
            Node temp=node.getChildNodes().item(i);
            if(temp.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("SONGTITLE")){
                return temp.getTextContent();
            }
        }
        return "Couldn't reach XML";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in getMetaData()", e);
        return "Exception ";
    }
}
```

Try running your app again and if an error arises from this method it will be printed in your logcat with the message "Error in getMetaData()". Update your question accordingly with the error to let other members help you.